# backing up files on a Linux VM

Tags: backup

I have created a VM using VirtualBox 6.0 and it has Ubuntu 18.04 installed.  The host machine is running Windows 10.  The purpose of setting up the Linux VM is to do mobile app development.

Initially, the plan was to have a folder on the host that would be shared with the guest because the host's folders are backed up on a regular basis.  Getting the shared folder to work has been largely unsuccessful - apparently because of different file system formats as described [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5824).  More specifically, when Expo projects are initialized they don't save properly to the shared folder and are unusable.  However, Expo projects save just fine when saved to a folder within the VM.

So what alternatives are out there for backing up files that are stored in a Linux VM?  I'm looking for something fairly simple as I'm new to Linux.

Comment: Have you considered using a cifs mount?

Comment: Never heard of it (I'm a Linux newbie).  Will do some Googling next.  Any further info you can share on that idea would be helpful.

Comment: CIFS is what Samba uses. Create a share on your Windows host system, then you can connect via Samba with your Ubuntu guest.

Comment: VM Snapshots? They are easy but have some downsides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a revision control system (e.g. mercurial, or subversion): put the working copy in the VM (so everything works), and the repository on the host (and/or remote).

This works, and you should be using revision control anyway.